# Multiple 4-wire PT100s with same excitation current?

Tags: pt100

Is there any potential loss of accuracy if I use the same excitation current for multiple 4 wire PT100s? Effectively connecting the excitation wires in series.

At present I am using one set of analog inputs (2 out of 4) on an AD7195 to measure voltage over a single PT100. I use AC excitation and feed the current through a precision resistor to act as a reference voltage. I am getting a 200 microKelvin resolution. I need to drive a second PT100 but without duplicating the precision (expensive) excitation components.

Answer (score 2):

In a perfect setup, no.

The thing I'd be aware of is, that you have different absolute voltages for each of your PT100, which might be an issue for your sense circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYTEQT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have 100 mV over each PT100, but for sensing the voltage across R1, you have a 300 mV offset (in this case).

It shouldn't be much of an issue, but depending on the voltages you work with, it might get out of range.

You must use the each pair of sense wires to keep the accuracy, although in the schematic two sense wires will effectively be at the same node (the one between R1 and R2 for example), in real life they will not have the same voltage (because there is another piece of wire between them).

One thing which might affect accuracy is the input current into each of the sense wires: each resistor will get less and less current, so you don't know how much current is actually going through each resistor. But with a good sense circuit this effect should become rather small.

With the AD7195 you should be fine as long as you don't exceed the maximum input voltage on the input (AVdd). I haven't seen any mention in the datasheet which would limit the common mode voltage. Input current in buffered mode is in the order of 5 nA, so you might wanna check if a missing current of 5 nA is a problem for you. If you are not using buffered mode, the input current is in the order of some µA, so it gets more noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

It's feasible, in fact we have done it with AC excitation.

There may be some subtle effects from stray capacitance on the leads since you are using (presumably very low frequency) AC. If you are using square waves then it probably won't matter.

There is also a typical AC common mode rejection spec of 120dB (and maximum is not given, but is significantly worse than typical at DC).